# ”User embeds a flipbook“ or "Users embed a flipbook"

Tags: singular-vs-plural

"User embeds a flipbook on his website but notices that there is a small report icon located on the right side of the flipbook. "

I want to know if "User" is correct. I thought I mean user in general and not a specific user. Should I use "Users", or "User"?

Comment: What's the context? Is this an anecdote? Is this a possible usage case? Who's the audience? I'm especially curious why it's in the simple present.

Comment: This is all very technical so you need to explain it. The user is probably better. Or users with an s.

Comment: You'd need to completely rewrite if you changed to the plural "users" (change all verbs and consider whether nouns needed to be pluralised): you can't just swap "user" for "users".

Comment: But it depends on context. It's common to use an abbreviated style in some contexts when writing software specifications, use cases, bug reports, etc, and in such cases the original version is fine.

Answer (score 0):

If you mean "in general", then it best to use the plural.

> Users embed...

This has the general sense that "all users do this thing".  If you do mean this it might be better to be explicit "All users embed..." It is quite possible that what you actually mean is "if" or "when" a user embeds a flipbook. Or you might actually mean "Some users..."

You will next run into the usual problem of multiple possession, since if there are multiple users, there would be multiple flipbooks, but perhaps only one per user. This creates problems: is it "Users embed flipbooks" or "Users embed a flipbook".  Both phrases have problems.

My preference would be to use "When...", with singular "they". This avoids the multiple possession, and lets you use the singular.

> When a user embeds a flipbook on their website, they will notice a small report icon...

Comment: Thanks for your help.

Comment: @James K Hi! I upvoted your good answer! Your good answer does not deserve a downvote!

Answer (score -1):

To make this grammatical, you can use an article before the subject:

"**The user** embeds a flipbook on his website but notices that there is a small report icon located on the right side of the flipbook."

or

"**A user** embeds a flipbook on his website but notices that there is a small report icon located on the right side of the flipbook."

If the a specific user has already been determined by context, you must use the definite article "the" to refer to this user.

Comment: Do you mean to directly use "User"  is incorrect?

Comment: Yes, you should use an article, or this will not be correct grammar.   It would be clear what you mean, but not good grammar.

Comment: Could I use "User" as a collective noun? "User uses System for personal purposes only"

Comment: You cannot use the collective singular with "user".    If you want to talk about a group of users, you must make the subject plural:  "**Users** use **the System** for personal purposes only."

Comment: Thanks for your help.